# Duplicate meta description for paging in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console, meta-description

In Google Webmaster tools I get duplicate content warnings for paging pages. How do I fix this? Do I need to add Page 2, Page 3, etc. to my meta description?

> HTML Improvements
>   Duplicate meta descriptions Meta description
>   information can give users a clear idea of your site's content and
>   encourage users to click on your site in the search results pages.

[image]

I have these already in place.

```
<link href="http://site.com/youth-basketball-tournaments?page=2" rel="canonical" /> 
<link rel="prev" href="/youth-basketball-tournaments?page=1" />
<link rel="next" href="/youth-basketball-tournaments?page=3" />
```

Comment: The problem of duplicate meta names has been asked many times on Pro Webmasters, and has been answered many times. The rel="canonical" link will resolve these problems combined with rel="next" and rel="prev" if your using paginated pages.

Comment: I have both these in place already for 6 months, those dont fix that problem.

Comment: Why would this be marked as a duplicate?  It has nothing to do with that question, its in regards to paging geez.

Comment: The question is in regards of duplicate meta descriptions, granted you are using prev and next, but none the less you have duplicate titles, as Zistoloen has suggested you should add page 2, page 3 to the description, additionally if you read the over posts on Pro Webmasters you can read about using a Canonical to a "view all" page that includes all of the pages into one format. You have many choices and many ways of doing this and as I said this has been discussed before in various threads regarding the use of canonical, prev/next and meta descriptions.

Comment: Also, it would be a silly idea to use noindex on pages2, 3, 4 etc without having a canonical view all. The best method would be to use page 2, page 3, page 4 in your meta descriptions and title, as well as a view all page that every single page is pointed to using the canonical link see > http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/view-all-in-search-results.html

Comment: If a view all page takes more then 5 minutes its not recommended, which it would.

Comment: @bybe: I don't see how this is a duplicate.  Yes there are similarities but this question has nuances that are not in the linked-to question.  Also the accepted answer on the linked-to question doesn't help someone looking for how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SEO, each webpage must have a personal `meta name="description"`.

Thus, a practice in your case is to add "*- Page 2*", "*- Page 3*" at the end of your `meta name="description"` tags in order to avoid duplicates.

Otherwise, you can just remove `meta name="description"` from these webpages (Page 2, Page 3...) and let Google fills them for you. This is how WordPress CMS works.

Comment: Is their an article on your suggestion?  I cant find anything.

Comment: It's just logical. The meta description of each webpage must perfectly describe the webpage content.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give another solution, most likely the best one.

Comment: Good idea on the removal part. I could keep it for page 1, then remove it for the rest, what you think?

Comment: I could also do a noindex, follow on pages 2 and up.

Comment: You can keep the meta description for Page 1 and remove for the rest, it's a good idea ;). Do not use `noindex` to index Page 2, Page 3 etc.

Comment: @MikeFlynn: here is an article that supports this answer: [Google’s Matt Cutts: Don’t Duplicate Your Meta Descriptions](http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-dont-duplicate-your-meta-descriptions-177706) and a video: [Is it necessary for every page to have a meta description?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4gr88oHb-k)